# Integration cloudfomation with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

how to integrate ansible with aws cloudfomation.

My playbook:

```
 - name: Provision Stack
   tasks:
     - name: launch ansible cloudformation example
       cloudformation:
         stack_name: "ansible-cloudformation"
         state: "present"
         region: "us-east-1"
         disable_rollback: true
         template: "~/cloudformation-example.json"
         tags:
           Stack: "ansible-cloudformation"
```

Error:
fatal:  FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-cloudformation\", line 2123, in \r\n    import os, boto3\r\nImportError: No module named boto3\r\n", "parsed": false}

I did install boto3.
python
import boto3 does not give any error

Answer (score 0):

Above Error as resolved when I used

`hosts: localhost

 connection: local`

Answer (score 0):

My Below code for the AWS cloudformation stack worked

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: create a cloudformation stack
      cloudformation:
       stack_name: "ansible-cloudformation"
       state: "present"
       region: "us-east-1"
       disable_rollback: true
       validate_certs: false
       template: "cloudformation.json"
       template_parameters:
         KeyName: "ansiblelearn.nitesh"
         DiskType: "ephemeral"
         ClusterSize: 3
       InstanceType: "t2.micro"
       tags:
         Stack: "ansible-cloudformation"
      register: cloudformation
```